# How do i add data from a variable to an array?

Tags: java, arrays

So basically I created an array.

```
int[] idarray = new int [5];
```

Now I want the user to input something.

```
idd = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("\nEnter ID number:\n\n");
id = Integer.parseInt(idd);
```

and whatever the data may be would go to the array `idarray`.

How do I add the data from the variable into the array?

Comment: You want an int to go in int[] right? Then to answer your question the index of location in your 'idarray' is needed where you want the 'id' to go.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should be using a `List<Integer>` (which would allow you to accept unlimited user input), but if you must use an array, this will work to fill your array from user input:

```
for (int i = 0; i < idarray.length; i++) {
    idd = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("\nEnter ID number:\n\n");
    id = Integer.parseInt(idd);
    idarray[i] = id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

idarray[i] = id; // of course you have to decide i yourself

if you want to simply appending things, you could use ArrayList instead of plain array.

Comment: whats i for? For the location of the array or for the number of items in the array?

Comment: location (index is a better term) of course, try reading your book