# How do i compare a variable's data with the data in an array?

Tags: java

I have an int array:

```
int[] BankClientNumber = new int[10];
```

I want the user to input an id number...

```
findidd = JOptionPane.showInputDialog ("\nEnter ID number:\n\n");
findid = Integer.parseInt(findidd);
```

...and have the program look through the data of the array, match the id number and print the other details of the client.

How do I compare the variable's data with that of the array?

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: As suggested in [your other recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214072/how-do-i-add-data-from-a-variable-to-an-array), use `List<Integer>` instead of `int[]`.

Answer (score 3):

You want to know if the int array contains the number, this is probably the esiest way:

```
Arrays.asList(BankClientNumber).contains(findidd)
```

*Note: As an advice I would use a `Collection` as `BankClientNumber` for instance a `Set`.*

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off storing the Bank Client Numbers in a Collection rather than an array. Collections have nice methods for searching, sorting etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a collection for whatever reason it's simply:

```
boolean exists = false;
for(int check: bankClientNumber) {
   if(check == findid) {
      exists = true;
      break;
   }
}
if(exists) {
   //do something
}
```

FYI Java coding conventions dictate that variables start in lowercase so `BankClientNumber` *should* be `bankClientNumber`.

Method names also start with lowercase and object names start with Uppercase.

It is also recommended to use camel cases (`youShouldUseCamelCase` or `YouShouldUseCamelCase`) and avoid underscores in method and object names. IMHO use camel case for variables as well.